# mouse move event conflict with touch event in IE11 of window 8.1pc

Tags: javascript, touch, internet-explorer-11, mousemove, mousedown

I created a web page for IE11 of window 8.1 tablet and window 8.1 pc. In this page, the scroll can be handled by javascript.

for html,

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; -ms-touch-action: none; touch-action: none; height: 100px" id="scrolledDiv">
   <table id="ContentTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
          <td>
            aaa
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
            aaa
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
            aaa
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
            aaa
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
            aaa
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
            aaa
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
            aaa
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
            aaa
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
            aaa
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
            aaa
          </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
<div>
```

In javascript,

```
var startY;
if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
   document.getElementById('scrolledDiv').addEventListener("MSPointerDown", 
     function(e){
       startY = e.pageY;
       e.preventDefault();
      }, false);

   document.getElementById('scrolledDiv').addEventListener("MSPointerMove", function(e){
        var touches = e.pageY;
        // override the touch event’s normal functionality
        e.preventDefault();

        // y-axis
        var touchMovedY = startY - touches;
        startY = touches; // reset startY for the next call
        document.getElementById('scrolledDiv').scrollTop = document.getElementById('scrolledDiv').scrollTop + touchMovedY;
      }, false);
}
```

When user makes touch event, the scroll is working well for IE 11 of window tablet 8.1. But when user makes mouse move in IE 11 of window 8.1 pc, it is working like touch event. I don't want to get scroll process in mouse move event in IE 11 of window 8.1 pc. How can I avoid this? Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I found the solution for this. There is pointerType property in pointer event object(e). I wrap the following snippet to my code.

```
if (e.pointerType == 'touch'){
  // your touch event code
}
```

Pointer type supports for touch, mouse and pen.